# Why do I need an include file for extern variables?

Tags: c++, extern

I found this:
[How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c)
and its main answer is rather clear to me.

However I do not understand why this gives me an error:

x.h :

```
#pragma once
namespace x {
   class A {
   public:  void func() const;
   };
   // extern A const a;  // cannot move this out of the include file !!!
   // extern int xi;     // fine to remove from here
}
```

--- main.cpp ---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "x.h"

namespace x { extern int xi; extern const A a ; }  // instead of include file

extern int i;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   std::cout << i << std::endl; // works
   std::cout << x::xi << std::endl; // works

   x::a.func();  

    return 0;
}
```

--- x.cpp ---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "x.h"

namespace x
{
   void A::func() const
   { std::cout << "x::A::func() called" << std::endl;  }

   const A a;  // Problem if const
   int xi = 234; // works
}
int i = 123;  // works
```

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class x::A const x::a" (?a@x@@3VA@1@B)
(VisualStudio 2013)
Compiling the two files is fine, and I can build and run it if I remove the const keyword, or if I move the extern statement into the include file.

Thanks for an explanation (can't believe in a compiler bug)  ;)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with C++, but I don't think `extern A const a;` (in x.h) and `extern const A a ;` (in main.cpp) are the same thing.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: Why's that?

Answer (score 3):

Namespace-scope `const` variables default to internal linkage (i.e., visible only within that translation unit). The `extern` is needed to override the default and give it external linkage (so that it can be accessed from a different translation unit).